# executing a python script in Django

Tags: python, django

I made a python script (a URL extractor with selenium)(myurl.py) and I want to print the output URL into an HTML button. I'm using Django.

Comment: executing it in a webpage http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41986273/selenium-scraping-javascript

Answer (score -1):

If you use Djano I don't know why you ask about PHP, but:

1. You can save this output in file via Python and then get its content by PHP.
2. You can use database. By Python script save output to record, then display its by PHP

Of course it's possible only when you are executing python script on the server where website is installed

Comment: executing it in a webpage http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41986273/selenium-scraping-javascript